# How to update entire JSON object in JSONB postgres column except 1 field

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

for example I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE fruit(id bigint, data jsonb);
```

and a row for example is:

```
1,    
{
   "type": "pinapple",
   "store1": {
   "first_added": "<some timestamp>",
   "price": "10",
   "store_id": "1",
   "comments": "some comments..."
},
   "store2": {
   "first_added": "<some timestamp>",
   "price": "11",
   "store_id": "2",
   "comments": "some comments..."
},
   .... more stores
}
```

In case of update I have the fruit id and store data :

```
1,
"store1": {
            "price": "12",
            "store_id": "1",
            "comments": "some comments...V2"
        }
```

I want to update entire store object in fruit entry (for store1), except the first_added field.

Any idea how I can accomplish it via JSONB operators or functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
UPDATE fruit
SET data = data || jsonb_set($1::jsonb, '{store1,first_added}', data#>'{store1,first_added}')
WHERE id = 1;
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e847cddd704284d5901cddc239a3dbc6))</sup>
where the parameter `$1` is set to the value `{"store1": {"price": "12", "store_id": "1", "comments": "some comments...V2"}}`.

Or if you need the key to be dynamic, use

```
UPDATE fruit
SET data = jsonb_set(data, ARRAY[$2::text], jsonb_set($1::jsonb, '{first_added}', data->$2->'first_added'))
WHERE id = 1;
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1262af10248b0702218193e33f4a423e))</sup>

Comment: looks great, but with store1 is dynamically changed? i.e., how it can be $2?

Comment: look great, thanks mate!, this is the query:  (same as in the dbfiddle, which is a great tool) `UPDATE fruit
SET data = jsonb_set(data, ARRAY[key], jsonb_set(json_value, '{first_added}', data->key->'first_added'))
FROM (VALUES('store1', '{"price": "12", "store_id": "1", "comments": "some comments...V2"}'::jsonb)) AS vals(key, json_value)
WHERE id = 1`;

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `jsonb_set` function to change the desired element, then use the `jsonb_build_object` function to create a new dataset, then concatenate the data with the `||` operator to keep the rest of the data(first_added,...)

```
update table1 
  set data = jsonb_set(data, '{store1}',  jsonb_build_object('first_added', data->'store1'->'first_added', 'price', 12, 'store_id', 1, 'comments', 'some comments...V2'))
where id  = 1;
```

Demo in [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4dffa08e2374c403ef60509fe8532fcb)

Comment: thanks, but I don't want to be depends in the store fields? i.e. those fields can be changed (added or removed), override all fields expects the first_added field

Comment: @ShayZambrovski But you are not dependent on store fields. If you add your fields to jsonb_build_object, they will also be added as new ones. Just if you specify those fields that are already in the store, then they are updated

Comment: @ShayZambrovski I understand you, you want to be able to change all the data of the store, but keep the first_added field, if so, then see my modified answer)

Comment: But still, I need to "know" all the fields, I want to avoid it.